# Which SQL join should I use here?

Tags: php, sql, join

I have got 2 SQL tables, one for user tables and one for all things about the user. (age, sex, etc)

user table:

```
id, username, mail, etc
```

second table

```
id, user_id, type_id, content
```

user table content:

```
1, knife, knife@something.com, etc ...
```

second table:

```
1, 1, 38 (age)
1, 3, Male
```

I would like to get the user who is between age 20-40 and who is male. 
I'm here now:

```
SELECT 
        *
FROM 
        felhasznalok_kieg_adat
        JOIN felhasznalok
                ON felhasznalok_kieg_adat.user_id = felhasznalok.id
WHERE 
   felhasznalok_kieg_adat.kieg_id = "22" 
   and felhasznalok_kieg_adat.tartalom < 21 
   and felhasznalok_kieg_adat.tartalom < 40
```

It shows me the results between ages 21 and 40, but How can I add that Male or female thing?

Comment: your second table output is really strange, how can same column contain both sex and age information?

Comment: yes correct @BojanKovacevic is your both values are inserted into same column?

Comment: aha,now i see type is different and define what content means. But would not be better if you have columns sex and age?

Comment: @BojanKovacevic - Think he's missing a column and the type id refers to the content type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join one time for the age filter, and a second time for the gender filter.

```
SELECT User.*
FROM User
    JOIN UserContent ageFilter
        ON ageFilter.user_id = User.id
        AND ageFilter.type_id = 1  -- use type_id for joining
    JOIN UserContent genderFilter
        ON genderFilter.user_id = User.id
        AND genderFilter.type_id = 3
WHERE (ageFilter.content < 21 AND ageFilter.content < 40) -- what type is content? You have to make some sort of conversion here!
AND (genderFilter.content = 'Male')
```

I have replaced the name of tables and columns by what you have described in your question.
Add the `type_id` in the join, it becomes much more readeable this way.

Comment: you should put a key explaining which tables are which to help the OP

Comment: I use the name he gives in his question.

Comment: I saw your solution first. I tried this one. It's actually working, but can I get this with the user id on id column. It gives me everythink, but for id it gives me not the id from the user table, but some other lines id. I dont need other tables id.

Comment: Yes I could... Thank you all very much.

Comment: For selecting only the value from user, write Select User.*... See edit

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM felhasznalok_kieg_adat
  JOIN felhasznalok ON felhasznalok_kieg_adat.user_id = felhasznalok.id
 WHERE ((felhasznalok_kieg_adat.kieg_id = "22" 
        AND felhasznalok_kieg_adat.tartalom < 21 
        AND felhasznalok_kieg_adat.tartalom < 40))
   AND felhasznalok_kieg_adat.gender = 'male'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick some values like 'M' for male and 'F' for female. Then:

```
ALTER TABLE felhasznalok_kieg_adat ADD COLUMN sex CHAR(1);
```

And your select for males only will look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM felhasznalok_kieg_adat
JOIN felhasznalok
ON felhasznalok_kieg_adat.user_id = felhasznalok.id
WHERE ((felhasznalok_kieg_adat.kieg_id = "22" and felhasznalok_kieg_adat.tartalom < 21 and felhasznalok_kieg_adat.tartalom < 40)) and (sex = 'M')
```

Answer (score 0):

**If possible if you are not having gender column you must add it in your table**

You can use [BETWEEN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)
in your join instead of > and < and you can join the table as

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.user_id = table2.id
WHERE ((table1.kieg_id = "22" and table1.tartalom BETWEEN 21 AND 22))


AND table1.gender = 'male'
```

Comment: I made it like this, cos I make user tables dynmic. I make registration form and user form dynamic. I can change the form easyli with this solution.